# worklogcomment view and use in Jql

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to view work-log comments of a user stories from filter in Jira. Can someone shed some light on how to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to access worklog comments from issue navigator in Jira. To access them you have to install one of the plugins that has worklog reports. As of now, [Tempo Timesheets](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6572/tempo-timesheets-time-tracking-report) and [Timesheet Reports and Gadgets](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/294/timesheet-reports-and-gadgets?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) are two most popular solutions for that.